# Template framework benchmark

Tags: java, mustache, template-engine, rythm, pebble

I have a requirement to prepare message from the predefined template, System which we are going to build will prepare 100 messages in a second. So i have written a program to build 1000 messages sequentially with multiple template framework available in the market which are

```
   -String template
   -Mustache template
   -Thymeleaf template
   -Rythm template
   -Pebble template
   -handler template
```

Template which i have used for this performance test contains some logic with multiple if/else , for and substitution statements.

To prepare 1000 messages sequentially. Endresult of these are listed below

```
  String template - 40 seconds
  Mustache template - 2 seconds
  Thymeleaf template - 15 seconds
  Rythm template   - 2 seconds
  Pebble template - 4 seconds
  Handler template - 7 seconds
```

In these i believe Rythm template beaten all other template framework.

Let me know your thoughts on Rythm template. Is there any drawback on using it.

Comment: If you are interested in fast templates expansion, take a look at Arco: It is based on JSPs and it compiles the templates to Java at compile-time. http://arco.samajackun.com/arco-maven-plugin/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

Hey Author of Rythm here. Thanks for putting Rythm into your benchmark list.

My understand about Rythm:

The good thing about Rythm is usability, feature set and expressiveness.

The drawback might be:

1. The jar is a bit fat
2. There is no IDE integration except vim

Comment: Rythm generates code and compile it when we hit at the first time. Is there a way to force it? because intial phase took morethan 5 seconds which i need to reduce it before i receive first request.

Comment: I think you can implement a "precompile" behavior in your Rythm plugin. You can refer to https://github.com/rythmengine/play-rythm/blob/master/src/org/rythmengine/play/RythmPlugin.java for detail

Answer (score 0):

One drawback i have seen is if there are any customized/userdefined function which can be used in multiple template then we need to write the same function in all templates. Is that my understanding right?

Comment: Not at all. Rythm provides the most flexible way of reusing your code. You can a) create another template and call it from any template (even include itself which is an recursive pattern) with any arguments; b) create a Java public method and call it within any templates; 

Refer to http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#reuse-methods-summary for more information about code reuse